# Text before title and all in one page in lyx

Tags: lyx, titles

I am writing an article in LyX using the `article.cls`. I need to have some text before the title. But in the pdf output this text appears in a separate page and the title and the rest of the article is pushed down to a fresh new page. I want all of this in one page -- the first page.

How do I get rid of this page break between the text and title?

Comment: Hi and welcome, this is an often asked question. You either need to redefine the `\maketitle` command (only if you want to have *that* title layout multiple times) or create a title on your own. Of course, package `titling` might be of some help using `\pretitle` or `\titlehooka`.

Comment: How do I create a title of my own! I am sorry but I am way dumb in all these than the dumbest.

Comment: LaTeX is a bit like a big LEGO set. I haven't ome around to extend an answer of mine to just article titles, right now it covers different variant of customizing whole title pages. But the workflow is nearly the same. [How to customize a titlepage](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/210280/37907).

Answer (score 4):

A dirty trick (I am too lazy to redefine `\maketitle`):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{doc}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
   Some {\em previous} text 

\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
   \maketitle
\end{minipage}

\section{Introduction}
    Lore ipsum ...
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

In LyX, with the `Insert`menu  you can make first a minipage. Then  define the title, authors and the date (in a a ERT if you want `\today`)  inside the minipage:

[image: MWE]

Note: The LaTeX generated with Lyx produce a minipage with the `[t]`op option and a width of `1\columnwidth`, where `\title`, `\authour` and `\date` are placed in the minipage (and not in the preamble as in the MWE), but the result is the same.